# How to handle allow/dismiss geo location popup on Android devices

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, saucelabs

[image]

I wanted to know how to handle geo location popup on Android devices

below are some high level details

1. I am using Saucelabs cloud to run my scripts
2. I am using Chrome browser
3. Android-emulator : Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus HD GoogleAPI Emulator
   Android- realdevice : Samsung_Galaxy_S10_POC173
4. Test environment : Selenium, Java, testNg

I have tried all the possible ways to handle this, attached are the code snippets that I have tried

Initially I thought it was an alert and tried to handle with switching to alert

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Then I tried with profile, but it is working fine for windows but not for android

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
HashMap<String, Object> contentSettings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
System.out.println("setting chrome options");
contentSettings.put("geolocation", 1);
profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentSettings);
prefs.put("profile", profile);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);*/
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(pcUrl), caps);
```

Then I tried by giving some options, that is also not able to handle the popup

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
options.addArguments("disable-geolocation");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
caps = caps.merge(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

I wanted to try below
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/handle-permission-pop-ups#handle-know-your-location-pop-up

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow']")).click();
```

But I am unable to type cast AndriodDriver to RemoteWebDriver, any suggestions on this

or if any other possible way is there to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an Appium session to drive Mobile Chrome, instead of Selenium.  That should allow you to interact with elements like you would in a Selenium test, but also change to the `NATIVE_APP` context to do things like dismiss popups.

You need to make a couple of changes:

1. Create an instance of `AndroidOptions` instead of `ChromeOptions`, then set the `browserName` capability to `Chrome`
2. Create an `AppiumDriver` of type `WebElement` instead of `RemoteWebDriver`

I was able to run a session and dismiss the popup like so:

```
    AndroidOptions options = new AndroidOptions();
    options.setCapability("deviceName","Google Pixel 3a GoogleAPI Emulator" );
    options.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.0");
    options.setCapability("automationName", "UIAutomator2");
    options.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");

    Map<String, Object> sauceOptions = new HashMap<>();
    sauceOptions.put("name", "WW");
    sauceOptions.put("appiumVersion", "1.20.2");
    options.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);

    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL(address),options);
```

```
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow']")).click();
```

You might have to dismiss a second popup from Android itself, as well:

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//android.widget.Button[@text='While using the app']")).click();
```